# argument of type int(*)[4] is incompatible with parameter type "int *". I am using visual studio

Tags: c, arrays

I am having an error in a c program of passing 2-d array to a function. error is as mentioned in the title. I am using visual studio 2015.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


int main()
{
 int display(int*, int, int);
 int a[3][4] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8,
    9, 0, 1, 6
    };
 display(a, 3, 4);
}
int display(int *q, int row, int col)
 {
  int i,j;
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
        printf("%d", *(q + i*col + j));
    printf("\n");
  }
 printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: try `display(a, 3, 4);` --> `display(&a[0][0], 3, 4);`. Also `display` must return int value. or Change `int` to `void`. and Use `row` and `col` instead of `2` and `3`.

Comment: If you change declaration from `int display(int *q, int row, int col)` to `int display(int row, int col, int q[row][col])` then you can call it directly as `display(3,4,q)`. Moreover, you use `q` as an array inside the function `display`. So, you can write `printf("%d", q[i][j]);` for example.

Comment: @Marian I think that MSVC2015 did not support VLA.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: MSVC never has been standard compliant. So one should use a compliant compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of this line

```
  display(a, 3, 4);
```

`a` is of type `int [3][4]` (array type), which decays to `int (*)[4]` (a pointer to the first element of the array) and an `int *` is not a match for it.

You need to adjust the function signature/call accordingly, i.e, either

- Change the parameter to `int (*)[4]` and use it accordingly.
- Change the call to pass the address of the first element of the first 1-D array, as mentioned the above comment by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy).

That said, seeing the missing `return` statement and the usage of the function call, you can safely change the return type of the function to be `void`.

Comment: Whatever you mentioned is already conveyed by error. Shouldn't your answer be a comment?

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni No, it's an answer. YMMV. :)

Answer (score -1):

Cast **a** to **(int*) a**, like this:

```
display( (int*) a, 3, 4 );
```